# Problem with implementing a socket listener in asp.net web-app

Tags: asp.net, sockets, web-applications, listener, port

I'm trying to bind the listening socket to a port and to accomplish that task i'm using the following lines of code:

```
    Socket listenSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    IPAddress hostIP = (Dns.Resolve(IPAddress.Any.ToString())).AddressList[0];
    IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint("localhost", 8372);
    listenSocket.Bind(ep);  
    listenSocket.Listen(backlog);
```

I found this code from [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.listen.aspx#Y940) msdn link. I'm just copying and pasting this code and using it in a class method as shown [here](http://postimage.org/image/1oygg6wn8/) but it seems like i'm not able to do it !! Do i have to implement some interface or do something else ??

Please help me

Thanks in anticipation

Comment: What happens that you say "it seems like i'm not able to do it !!" ?

Comment: @babak i'm getting an error as you can see in the link i posted "A get or set accessor expected" !! I don't understand it !!

Comment: The web filter where I am blocked your link: "This Websense category is filtered: Sex."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code in the image you linked to has an error: `portSocketListener` is coded as if it's a method but it's missing the `()` parentheses that turn it into a method.

Try replacing the entire thing with:

```
public void portSocketListener() // <-- Here's the error
{
    Socket listenSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    IPAddress hostIP = (Dns.Resolve(IPAddress.Any.ToString())).AddressList[0];
    IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(hostIP, 8372);
    listenSocket.Bind(ep);
    listenSocket.Listen(1);
}
```

Comment: @Daniel http://postimage.org/image/1eiwj3x50/ i'm getting these errors. Please help me !!

Comment: You changed the code from MSDN, use `hostIP` instead of `"localhost"`

Comment: @Daniel What should i write in the place of backlog variable ?? I mean this line listenSocket.Listen(BACKLOG); What should I write there ?? Visual studio editor says it should be integer? Please have a look at this: http://postimage.org/image/1enyg83gk/

Comment: Read the docs you linked to: `The backlog parameter specifies the number of incoming connections that can be queued for acceptance.`  Try setting it to `1` initially but you may want a higher value depending on what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Daniel http://postimage.org/image/1p8sk3zr8/ this is the error i'm getting, can u please elucidate what can be the reason for this error ?

Comment: You're trying to open a listening socket inside an ASP.NET page request!? That sounds like madness! What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @Daniel I'm using Db4o a object oriented database. I want to open a client so that it can access the database table which in turn calls the server to do so.Here is the link to those lines of code: http://postimage.org/image/1pdm7jflw/.  What i'm trying to do by the portSocketListener() method is try to open a port and listen to it from where the client can access the data. I don't know if my approach is wrong. May be u can help me !!

Comment: @user653622 you might want to take down that image, it appears to include a username & password.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Db4o but needing to open a socket to communicate with a database system sounds very strange. Making the client *listen* is even more unusual, surely it's the Db4o database server that's listening for connections?

Comment: @Daniel Ok thanks for your immediate feedback. I do appreciate it !!